# playwright - some urls make page.goto hangup and set timeouts didn't resolved

Tags: timeout, playwright

The url in the code below (and some others that i'm finding) exists but the https server don't answer, so try to verify response.code >= 400 don't work. Set page timeouts also don't work. Problem is, i have to run a list of urls and when the script find one it hangup.

```
    url = 'https://mediafina.xyz'

    page.set_default_timeout = 120000
    page.set_default_navigation_timeout = 120000
    page.goto(url)
```

If i run showing the browser page on the screen

```
    browser = pw.chromium.launch({
        ...
        headless=False,
        ...
    }
```

The browser show in a minute or so:

```
Unable to access this site
mediafina.xyz has unexpectedly terminated the connection.
```

But i don't know how to get this event, if this is a playwright event. Google wasn't helpful.

What i'm missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

```
def response_handler(response):
    if response.ok == False:
        page.close()

page.on("response", response_handler)
```

BEFORE page.goto(url) and now playwright don't hangup anymore.